Vue3 event listeners cannot set properties of undefined
I've recently started using Vue3 after a couple year gap and have opted for the Composition API.
The issue I have is with the 2 event listeners in the onMounted function.
This is what I get for the first event listener

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
'width')
at HTMLDivElement.

This is the error I get for the second event listener

Uncaught  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
'contains')
at HTMLDivElement.

and this is the extract of my code that causing the problem
<script setup>
  import { defineProps, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import { useEventListener } from '@vueuse/core'

  const waveForm = ref(null)
  const hover = ref()
  const mainCover = ref(null)

  onMounted(() => {
    useEventListener(waveForm, 'pointermove', (evt) => {
      hover.style.width = `${evt.offsetX}px`
    })

    useEventListener(mainCover, 'click', (e) => {
      if (mainCover.classList.contains("active")) {
        mainCover.classList.remove("active");
        mainCover.classList.add("inactive");
      } else {
        mainCover.classList.remove("inactive");
        mainCover.classList.add("active");
      }
    })
  })

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="mainCover" id="main_cover">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ref="waveForm" id="waveform">
    <div ref="hover" id="hover"></div>
  </div>>
</template>


there are several issues in the code snippet:

You should use mainCover.value instead of mainConver for manipulating styles.

Adding empty check to ensure the element exists.
<script setup>
 import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
 import { useEventListener } from '@vueuse/core';

 const waveForm = ref(null);
 const hover = ref(null);
 const mainCover = ref(null);

 onMounted(() => {
   useEventListener(waveForm, 'pointermove', (evt) => {
     if (hover.value) {
       hover.value.style.width = `${evt.offsetX}px`;
     } else {
       console.error('hover is null or undefined');
     }
   });

   useEventListener(mainCover, 'click', () => {
     if (mainCover.value) {
       mainCover.value.classList.toggle('active');
       mainCover.value.classList.toggle('inactive');
     } else {
       console.error('mainCover is null or undefined');
     }
   });
 });
 </script>

 <template>
   <div>
     <div ref="mainCover" id="main_cover">a</div>
   </div>
   <div ref="waveForm" id="waveform">
     <div ref="hover" id="hover"></div>
   </div>
 </template>




You cannot modify directly your ref() variables, instead you should access to its value first. Try this
  onMounted(() => {
useEventListener(waveForm, 'pointermove', (evt) => {
  hover.value.style.width = `${evt.offsetX}px`
})

useEventListener(mainCover, 'click', (e) => {
  if (mainCover.classList.contains("active")) {
    mainCover.value.classList.remove("active");
    mainCover.value.classList.add("inactive");
  } else {
    mainCover.value.classList.remove("inactive");
    mainCover.value.classList.add("active");
  }
})

